# JQuery.inArray issue

Tags: jquery, arrays

I dont understand why it output me -1 for the JQuery.inArray, I clicked on the td 2. It should print 1.

This is the HTML :

```
 <table id="numberTable" class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="red">1</td>
              <td class="black">2</td>
              <td class="red">3</td>
              <td class="black">4</td>
              <td class="red">5</td>
              <td class="black">6</td>
            <tr>
```

The script :

```
$('table tr td').click(function(){
// Initialisation
  var number = $(this).text();
  // Datas
  var data = new Array();
  data['listBlackMethod'] = [2,4,6,8,10,11,13,15,17,20,22,24,28,29,31,33,35];
// Traitement
console.log(number);
console.log(data['listBlackMethod']);
//console.log()
console.log(jQuery.inArray(number,data['listBlackMethod']));
```

The output

```
2                                                        qqqspinguess.js:55:13
Array(17) [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, … ]      spinguess.js:56:13
-1                                                       spinguess.js:58:13
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to `.inArray`, The comparison between values is strict. The following will return -1 (not found) because a string is being searched in an array of numbers:

```
console.log(jQuery.inArray(number,data['listBlackMethod']));
```

> String:

```
var number = $(this).text();
```

> Number:

```
data['listBlackMethod']
```

Comment: Did this fix your issue?